# Migrate from Sourceforge to Github

Tags: github, sourceforge

I'm thinking about migrating a project from Sourceforge to Github. Besides the svn to git, what about migrating things like the issue tracker? Is there an easy way to do that?

Comment: I am not sure there is an easy way. I would try the [GitHub Issues API](http://develop.github.com/p/issues.html) and try to move those myself. In fact if you search GitHub, you might find a gist or repository that has a ready made solution that uses the GitHub API.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I've written a Python script to migrate issues. It's at https://github.com/ttencate/sf2github.

Beware: Sunday afternoon software. Use at your own risk, etc. etc. Pull requests welcome!

Comment: This tool has problems with throttling because it uses the old GitHub Issues API. You probably want to use the more up to date https://github.com/cmungall/gosf2github instead.

Comment: Sir @SergeyPonomarev you "more up to date repo" hasn't been updated for the last 2 years! any newer solutions?

Comment: Just see Forks Network tab on the repo to see forks that are updated

Comment: Thanks @SergeyPonomarev for this very helpful utility. The only problem I experienced was the mismatch between SF and GH users, which wasn't actually completely solved by the user mapping. I had to set the "assigned_to" fields to null for those (old) SF users who don't exist on github

Answer (score 23):

For SVN to GitHub part, this is now the easiest way: https://github.com/new/import

Help page: https://help.github.com/en/github/importing-your-projects-to-github/importing-a-repository-with-github-importer

**But it doesn't import issues.**

Comment: easiest way for git to git too.

Comment: I am currently trying this with an old SourceForge repository and it has told me over and over:
"No source repositories were detected at https://sourceforge.net/projects/projectName/. Please check the URL and try again."

I've tried various links from it. There is nothing anywhere on the SourceForge page to suggest there's another URL to use.
So this answer may be "the easiest way" to import repositories into GitHub, but it apparently no longer applies to SourceForge, which is the question.

Comment: @ChuckkHubbard: That's because from https://github.com/new/import you have to import the SVN URL (in my case https://svn.code.sf.net/p/msgtext/code/) as mentioned instead of the SourceForge project URL (in my case https://sourceforge.net/projects/msgtext/)

Comment: That page now says: "Support for importing Mercurial, Subversion and Team Foundation Version Control (TFVC) repositories will end on April 12, 2024.". So if anybody wants to go this way he should hurry up.

Answer (score 15):

since I just have done this here is my approach

create a local git repository from the remote svn repository

```
git svn clone http://svn/repo/here/trunk
```

now push the repository to github

```
git remote rename origin upstream
git remote add origin git@github.com:myname/myproject.git
git push origin master
```

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://gist.github.com/976886) script uses rsync to sync the raw svn repo onto your /tmp directory and requires the svn2git ruby gem for importing the svn commit info into git.

If you happen to use a newer version of the SVN infrastructure provided by sourceforge (aka SVN 2.0 dev), you can use [this](https://gist.github.com/2968478) script instead - I forked off the original to just make changes to the rsync command. :)